# Using GoogleApiClient in a service

Tags: android, android-service, google-api-client

I am trying to get location update information in service. For this I have  created a service and in onStartCommand of service class I am creating GoogleApiClient, but I am not getting connection call back in the service. Please help to resolve this.

Below given is the service code and in activity I have started service using startService method :

```
startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
```

service code

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
                    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private GoogleApiClient mLocationClient;

private Location mCurrentLocation;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO do something useful
    Toast.makeText(this, "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(LocationService.this)
    .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(LocationService.this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(LocationService.this).build();

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    Toast.makeText(this, mCurrentLocation.getLatitude() +", "+ mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //if(servicesConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    //}

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: bro i'm also working on same thing.I need current location by using service. How do you did bro.I need solution.Help me out

Answer (score 16):

The main issue: you never call [mLocationClient.connect()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#connect()) so the connection process never starts.

Also, `onStartService()` can be called multiple times (i.e., every time `startService()` is called - instead, you should move this to `onCreate()` for your `Service` to ensure it is only called once during the lifecycle of your Service. Similarly, you should [removeLocationUpdates()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#removeLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener)) in `onDestroy()` and disconnect your `mLocationClient`.

Comment: +1 for the .connect() as I missed that, but there's still no guarantee his IntentService will be around when the connected callbacks are called.

Comment: @BillMote - it pretty clearly says `extends Service` - where do you see `IntentService`?

Comment: Man, you're right.  IDK ... I would have sworn it was an IntentService.  I guess it's time for bed.