# get location using GoogleAPIClient in Service

Tags: android, service, android-googleapiclient

I want to get location in background so that I can fetch location from any activity/fragment. problem is I'm not getting the latitude and longitude in Service. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

```html
public class LocationService extends Service implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = "sammy_";
    private boolean currentlyProcessingLocation = false;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private Location mCurrentLocation;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       
            startTracking();     

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private void startTracking() {
        Log.d(TAG, "startTracking");      

            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();

            
      
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mCurrentLocation = location;
        System.out.println("Current LAT: "+mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()+ " Current LANG: "+mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
    }

    private void stopLocationUpdates() {
        if (googleApiClient != null && googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected");

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000); 
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000); 
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        /*if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }*/


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed");

        stopLocationUpdates();
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.e(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Using GoogleApiClient in a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712244/using-googleapiclient-in-a-service)

It looks like you need to connect to the Google API (and should also move GoogleApi code to onCreate() ).